# Different versions of compilers + libgcc on windows encountered

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2, libgcc

I have a third-party library which depends on `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`.
My own program is compiled under MSYS2 (mingw-w64) and it depends on `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`.

Please note that the third-party library is pure binaries (no source). Please also note that both `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` and `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` are 32-bit, so I don't think it's an issue related to architecture.

The outcome is apparent, programs compiled based on `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` can't work with third-party libraries based on `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`. What I get is a missing entrypoint `__gxx_personality_sj0`.

I can definitely try to adapt my toolchain to align with the third-party's `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`, but I do not know how much effort I need to go about doing it. I find no such variant of libgcc dll under MSYS2 using this setjmp/longjmp version. I am even afraid that I need to eliminate the entire toolchain because all the binaries I had under MSYS2 sits atop this `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` module.

My goal is straightforward: I would like to find a solution so that my code will sit on top of `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` instead of `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`. But I don't know if I am asking a stupid question simply because this is just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The terms dw2 and sjlj refer to two different types of exception handling that GCC can use on Windows.  I don't know the details, but I wouldn't try to link binaries using the different types.  Since MSYS2 does not provide an sjlj toolchain, you'll have to find one somewhere else.  I would recommend downloading one from the "MingW-W64-builds" project, which you can find listed on this page:

https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download

You could use MSYS2 as a Bash shell but you can probably not link to any of its libraries in your program; you would need to recompile all libraries yourself (except for this closed source third-party one).